# Remove old data based on stamp mySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to remove all data in my table with a stamp older than for example 2 days. I have created the following Query:

```
DELETE FROM temporary_data WHERE stamp < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

But this does not seem to work. My stamp looks like this:  2014-04-29 15:37:00

I think it's with the CURDATE() that returns only 2014-04-30 which is not matching a stamp. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always Select Before Delete

```
SELECT from temporary_data
where stamp between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) and now();
```

Delete Query

```
delete from temporary_data
where stamp between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) and now();
```

You can modify Interval based on your requirement, for more reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Older than 2 days from now could be deleted as

```
DELETE FROM temporary_data WHERE stamp <  date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 day)
```

Here how in mysql it looks like

```
mysql> select now(),date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 day) ;
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| now()               | date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 day) |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
| 2014-04-30 12:54:39 | 2014-04-28 12:54:39            |
+---------------------+--------------------------------+
```

And without `H:i:s` it should be as

```
mysql> select CURDATE(),date(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 day)) ;
+------------+--------------------------------------+
| CURDATE()  | date(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 2 day)) |
+------------+--------------------------------------+
| 2014-04-30 | 2014-04-28                           |
+------------+--------------------------------------+
```